# Switch in action bar doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I want to put Switch into Action Bar and set for the Switch `OnCheckedChangeListener`. 
Here is my code:
**check_words_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_action_bar"/>
</menu>
```

**switch_action_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and **SomeFragment.java**

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
// ...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.check_words_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch);
    item.setActionView(R.layout.switch_action_bar);
    Switch mySwitch = (Switch) item.getActionView();
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // some code
}
```

After running I get ClassCastException:

> 03-18 13:39:55.750    7206-7206/com.chubarich.android.translator E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Switch
>               at com.chubarich.android.translator.CheckWordsFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(CheckWordsFragment.java:65)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1871)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2714)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:979)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:115)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4954)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

65 line is `Switch mySwitch = (Switch) item.getActionView();` in **SomeFragment.java**.
Tell me please, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Switch mySwitch = (Switch) item.getActionView();
```

Change the above line to

```
View actionView=item.getActionView();
Switch mySwitch = (Switch)actionView.findViewById(R.id.switch_id);
```